# Run javascript on aspx page after clicking a button with actual values

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

by clicking on a button on my aspx page I'm generating a .csv file for using in javascript dygraph:

```
protected void btn_start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
.....

System.IO.File.WriteAllText(MapPath("~/Data/") + authuser + "_data.csv", data);
```

Later also in the same button click event I fill a div container (is empty on `Page_Load`) with the javascript code for dygraph with the .csv as source:

```
protected void btn_start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
.....

System.IO.File.WriteAllText(MapPath("~/Data/") + authuser + "_data.csv", data);
.....

string strDiagram = @"<script type=""text/javascript"">
                      chart = new Dygraph(document.getElementById(""MainContent_DivDiagramm""), 'http://webserver/test/Data/" + authuser + @"_data.csv',... //String reduced here
.....

DivDiagramm.InnerHtml = strDiagram;
```

It is all working but with old data. For example I generate the .csv with data for two weeks the first time I open the page the dygraph remain empty. Then I generate on the page data for 3 weeks then I get displayed the dygraph with the data for 2 weeks. So it is always taken the old data.

So how can I tell javascript to take always the new generated .csv and not the old one from the session before? Also tried on `Page_Complete` but with the same result. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add some kind of versioning query string to your CSV-file url when accessing it in JavaScript, e.g:

```
chart = new Dygraph(
    document.getElementById(""MainContent_DivDiagramm""), 
    'http://webserver/test/Data/" + authuser + @"_data.csv?v=" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString() + "');"
```